# Backspace not work on Contenteditable div in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, range, contenteditable

I use the following program to insert the text and update the cursor in a `contenteditable` `div`. (It is an autocomplete feature.)

```
var sel, range;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
        // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = node;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);

        // Preserve the selection
        if (lastNode) {
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    // IE < 9
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(node);
}
```

Text is properly inserted at the cursor position and the cursor is updated properly. However, the issue (which I am able to reproduce only in Firefox) is as follows:

1. Use the above program to insert the text.
2. Focus out of the `contenteditable` `div` by focusing on another element.
3. Now again get back to the `contenteditable` `div`.
4. Get the cursor to the end.
5. Try the backspace button.

It does not remove the text. (Backspace does not work.)

Comment: Could you setup a JSFiddle (or similar) with your code so we can play around with it and try to get it working?

Comment: I've removed the rangy tag from your question and put range instead because you call `window.getSelection` and so Rangy (which is a specific library) is not used in the code you've shown. And welcome to the mess that is `contenteditable`. Browsers do not treat editable elements consistently, as you've just discovered.

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8vcy9/6/
Steps to reproduce the scenario:
  1) Keep the cursor between some and editable and then click insert node to insert text
  2) then click outside contenteditable div multiple times (in different tabs of jsfiddle like js/ html/css  and type some chars in  
check form)
 3) Then try to delete the last inserted "character" using backspace. It does not work.

Please let me know if I have made any mistakes because I am new to this range..

Comment: Please find the fiddle : @Turnerj

Comment: Hmmm, couldn't recreate it in Chrome but I can in Firefox (I didn't actually notice you had the Firefox tag *duh*)

Comment: OK, it seems that at least with JSFiddle, the wrong element ends up with focus when following those instructions. The text area for either HTML, Javascript or CSS is still the active element. I've got to do a few more tests so will get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi All,
I am still not seeing any solutions for this. Can someone help me in solving this issue???